# "Publish in Access Services" in access with Sharepoint 2007 not working because of Table "UserInfo"

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to use "Publish in Access Services" with a Sharepoint 2007 server. The thing is, I have a problem where it tells me that I can't do that thanks to the "UserInfo" table that happens to be a reserved name. What can I do to correct this? Is there a way of changing the table name or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not aware that you can publish to SharePoint 2007. However the terminology somewhat changed. And there is a significant difference between SharePoint 2007 and 2010 when you use the term "publish".

However, ignoring all of the above, one thing is to simply delete the table (or make a copy). You can then publish your database. At that point you then LINK to the UserInfo table that is available for all published databases (regardless of the new publishing that Access 2010 has that allows you to create Access form  that run in an web browser.